# Flutter - How to get Rounded border when scrolling listview?

Tags: listview, flutter, dart, android-listview, android-chips

I'm having listview with chips in bottom of the Column.

In first image from starting in listview its in circular shape but in the end its shows as rectangle.

[image: First Image]

When scrolling the listview Chip 1 day is overflow.(Second Image).

[image: Second Image]

I want both side bottom need to circular, How to achieve? Thanks in Advance.

My Code

```
Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 16.0,
                ),
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: 100,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                    color: Colors.white),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(""),
                    Container(
                      height: 35,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(12.0),
                              bottomRight: Radius.circular(12.0)),
                          color:
                              Theme.of(context).chipTheme.backgroundColor),
                      child: ListView(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        children: getChoiceChips(),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
```

Chip Function

```
getChoiceChips() {
List<Widget> choiceChipList = [];
List<String> choiceString = [
  '1 Day',
  '1 Week',
  '1 Month',
  '3 Months',
  '1 Year'
];
for (String choice in choiceString) {
  choiceChipList.add(Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 2.0, right: 2.0),
    child: ChoiceChip(
      label: Text(choice),
      selected: choice == selectedChoice,
      onSelected: (newSelectedChoice) {
        setState(() {
          print(selectedChoice);
          print(newSelectedChoice);
          selectedChoice = choice;


          print(selectedChoice);
          print(choice);
        });
      },
    ),
  ));
}
return choiceChipList;
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `BoxDecoration` in the `Container` will only show the rounded corners as a visual feature. If you want to actually clip the contents to within those rounded corners with no overflow, you want to surround the container in a [`ClipRRect`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipRRect-class.html).

```dart
ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
  child: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    height: 100,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
    child: Column(
      ...
    ),
  ),
),
```